# Job for ospd-openvas.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: openvas

after typing the command sudo gvm-check-setup, the process is stopped at step-1 itself, and is showing the error that:
Job for ospd-openvas.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ospd-openvas.service" and "journalctl -xeu ospd-openvas.service" for details.
how to resolve this issue to start the ospd-openvas service.

i tried all the commands mentioned above along with some other relevant commands. I tried to remove the gvm and re installed it, then again gave the command sudo gvm-setup, after that sudo gvm-check-setup but i am getting the same error again.

[check the image for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JArk7.jpg)